# Работа с Common Intermediate Language

Tags: .net, ide, cil

В последнее время достаточно интересно стало писать на [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), дабы поближе ознакомиться со всем тем, с чем я работаю каждый день)

В связи с этим появился вопрос: есть ли какая-нибудь `IDE` для разработки приложений на чистом `IL`, а также чем бы следовало вооружиться для более детального его изучения (ибо пока в моем арсенале есть только интуиция, с помощью которой я читал `IL` ранее, и [страничка со списком инструкций на Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions))

Пока что я нашел только [расширение для Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ins0mniaque.ILSupport), но оно позволяет лишь интегрировать инструкции на `IL` в код на `C#`, `F#` или `VB`, а это не совсем то, что мне хотелось бы видеть ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15826739/2881286), там говорят есть еще [xacc](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xacc/) какой-то но он уже 4 года не обновлялся. И еще [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3887962/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy: `xacc` не поддерживает компиляцию `IL`-кода. Только подсветку)

Comment: Мопед не мой :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> есть ли какая-нибудь IDE для разработки приложений на чистом IL

Как вариант, сделать саму Visual Studio такой IDE, пользуясь пользовательскими шаблонами.

## I. Шаблон проекта

Создадим проект консольного приложения C#, назовем его, скажем, CilProject.

В обозревателе решений в контекстном меню проекта вызовем пункт "Выгрузить проект". Там же у выгруженного проекта вызовем пункт "Изменить проект".

Найдем в XML узел

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets>
```

И заменим его на следующий код:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets" />

  <Target Name="CreateManifestResourceNames" />

  <Target Name="CoreCompile" Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);@(Compile);" Outputs="@(IntermediateAssembly);">
    <GetFrameworkPath>
      <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="FrameworkPath" />
    </GetFrameworkPath>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <IlAsmCommand>&quot;$(FrameworkPath)\Ilasm.exe&quot; /NOLOGO /DLL /OUTPUT:&quot;@(IntermediateAssembly)&quot; </IlAsmCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' " >
      <IlAsmCommand>$(IlAsmCommand) /DEBUG </IlAsmCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' " ><IlAsmCommand>$(IlAsmCommand) /OPTIMIZE </IlAsmCommand></PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile)' != '' " >
      <IlAsmCommand>$(IlAsmCommand) /KEY:&quot;$(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile)&quot; </IlAsmCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Exec Command="$(IlAsmCommand) @(Compile->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')" 
          Outputs="@(IntermediateAssembly)" />

    <CallTarget Targets="$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)" Condition="'$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)' != ''" />
  </Target>
```

Снова загрузим проект (в том же контекстном меню выберем пункт "Перезагрузить проект").

Заменим AssemblyInfo.cs на AssemblyInfo.il:

```
.assembly CilProject { }
```

Заменим Program.cs на Program.il:

```
.method public static void Main() cil managed
{
     .entrypoint
     .maxstack 1
    ldstr "Hello, world!"
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    call int32 [mscorlib]System.Console::Read()
    pop
    ret
}
```

Для обоих .il файлов в свойствах установим *Действие при сборке* - *Компилировать*. После этого проект должен собираться и запускаться.

В Visual Studio выберем *Проект - Экспорт шаблона - Шаблон проекта*, в диалоговом окне введем имя и описание и установим галку "Автоматически импортировать в Visual Studio". В результате должен получиться такой шаблон CilProject.csproj (для VS 2017 и .NET 4.0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{$guid1$}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>$safeprojectname$</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>$safeprojectname$</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.il" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.il" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets" />
  <Target Name="CreateManifestResourceNames" />
  <Target Name="CoreCompile" Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);@(Compile);" Outputs="@(IntermediateAssembly);">
    <GetFrameworkPath>
      <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="FrameworkPath" />
    </GetFrameworkPath>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <IlAsmCommand>"$(FrameworkPath)\Ilasm.exe" /NOLOGO /OUTPUT:"@(IntermediateAssembly)" </IlAsmCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
      <IlAsmCommand>$(IlAsmCommand) /DEBUG </IlAsmCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
      <IlAsmCommand>$(IlAsmCommand) /OPTIMIZE </IlAsmCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile)' != '' ">
      <IlAsmCommand>$(IlAsmCommand) /KEY:"$(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile)" </IlAsmCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(IlAsmCommand) @(Compile->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')" Outputs="@(IntermediateAssembly)" />
    <CallTarget Targets="$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)" Condition="'$(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation)' != ''" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Файл шаблона будет помещен в `(Мои документы)\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates`. После этого в окне создания проекта в категории Visual C# появится наш CilProject.

[image: CilProject]

Уже можно писать программы (ссылки на сборки вписывать в AssemblyInfo.il, а код добавлять в виде файлов .il с действием при сборке "Компилировать").

## II. Шаблон элемента

Для удобства создадим также шаблон класса. Добавим файл Class1.il:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Class1
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig static void Method() cil managed
    {       
        ret
    }
}
```

В Visual Studio выберем *Проект - Экспорт шаблона - Шаблон элемента*, в диалоговом окне выберем файл *Class1.il*, установим галку "Автоматически импортировать в Visual Studio" и введем остальные параметры. Получим zip-файл с шаблоном в каталоге `(Мои документы)\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ItemTemplates`, распакуем его и откроем файл .vstemplate. В нем найдем узел `<ProjectItem...>` и добавим в него атрибут `ItemType="Compile"`:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>CilClass.il</DefaultName>
    <Name>CilClass</Name>
    <Description>Class (CIL)</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem ItemType="Compile" SubType="" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.il" ReplaceParameters="true">Class1.il</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Запакуем файлы в такой же ZIP-архив и поместим на место старого в каталоге *ItemTemplates*. Перезапустим студию, после этого в окне добавления элемента, в категории "Элементы Visual C#" появится наш шаблон класса.

[image: CilClass]

## Результат

Что-то такое:

[image: IDE]

Плюсы: работает отладка, вывод ошибок и предупреждений компилятора с указанием файла и строки, можно переключаться между конфигурациями Debug/Release.

Минусы: не работают свойства проекта, функционал добавления ссылок через интерфейс студии, подсветка синтаксиса, проверка ошибок во время редактирования и многое другое.

Итоговые файлы шаблонов: [шаблон проекта](https://yadi.sk/d/iQZtbjkndUkCcw), [шаблон элемента](https://yadi.sk/d/TcAYNnJcj5N2uQ).

> чем бы следовало вооружиться для более детального его изучения

Утилитой [IL Disassembler](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler), документацией класса [System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes?view=netframework-4.7.2), третьим разделом [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

## Источники

[Visual Studio Project and item templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2017)

[How can i load a template I have created in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381941/how-can-i-load-a-template-i-have-created-in-visual-studio)

[Are there any examples of compiling CIL code from within a Visual Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076917/8674428)

Comment: Ох уж Вы и правда белый рыцарь) Спасибо Вам огромное за такой развёрнутый ответ! Вы не против, если я на основе Вашего ответа через некоторое время напишу расширение для VS, добавляющее шаблоны IL-проектов и подсветку синтаксиса?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Не против

Comment: Благодарю покорно)

Comment: `$(NonExistentFile)` в списке выходных элементов тут лишний. Эта штука применяется когда компилятор встроен в студию, а вы запускаете внешний exe-файл.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov если всерьез займетесь этим - не забудьте автогенерировать файл со ссылками на сборки исходя из `@(ReferencePath)`. Это не так сложно автоматизируется чтобы заставлять программиста страдать этим самостоятельно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, согласен с Вами) Спасибо за совет!